# 3D in co-op in Epic Mickey 2 on XBox 360

Tags: xbox-360, stereo-3d, epic-mickey-2

Is it possible to activate stereoscopic 3D in co-op in Epic Mickey 2 on XBox 360?

Comment: I would not imagine so, as the stereoscopic 3D is dependent on having enough room for two images. And as I am assuming the co-op you are describing, is split screen. There just wouldn't be enough room. However, if it were possible, there would be some option to do so. Or it would remain on, when starting co-op.

Comment: I've heard about games that do offer stereoscopic 3D in split-screen, cant remember their titles now though. But I think the limiting factor would be the hardware and not the "room".